# Bash script to batch process files in sets of 2; how do I pass on the 2nd filename

Tags: bash

A colleague wrote a nice script to convert an XML document into a different XML file with formatting compatible with our workflow. Unfortunately, he didn't build in the ability to process thousands of files. This site helped me before to do a similar task, but I couldn't figure out the extrapolation.

There's an image file, with a corresponding XML file with annotation information (filename1.ndpi and filename1.ndpi.ndpa). The syntax is:

```
python myscript.py filename1.ndpi filename1.ndpi.ndpa
```

Which outputs a new XML file: image-filename.ndpi.xml

Based on a previous question I wrote the following batch file:

```
#!/bin/sh
for filename1 in ls *.ndpi filename2 in 'ls *.ndpa'; do python myscript.py "$filename1" "$filename2" 
done
```

It seems like a relatively straightforward thing, but I'm definitely doing something wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ for f in *.ndpi; do script.py "$f" "$f.ndpa"; done
```

Comment: Thanks! Very elegant solution!